# ¿Por que me marca error en mi metodo guardar(), si ya esta creado (Angular Spring Boot)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

[image: introducir de la imagen aquí]
El método Guardar ya fue creado y aun así no lo reconoce, no se que podría ser, ya revise el código y al parecer esta bien.

Comment: Por favor, usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/438352/edit) y añade tu código en formato de texto, una imagen con código solo complica la lectura

Comment: Si no pones el código como te podemos ayudar?. `Guardar()` con mayúsculas?